# Can I use the verb "disappear" in Present Continuous Tense?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, present-continuous

"More and more forests are disappearing because of fires." or "More and more forests disappear because of fires." which one is grammatically correct?  Our English teacher said that disappear is a stative verb. I am not sure if she is right or wrong, because she makes a lot of grammatical mistakes while teaching and I always notice it. But maybe I am the wrong one

Comment: Would you think 'More forests seem to be disappearing every year' is wrong? 'Disappear' can be punctive (Dumbledore disappeared in that infuriating way of his) or refer to a gradual process.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that it can't? :)

Answer (score 5):

Both are correct. The verb *disappear* is frequently used in the present continuous: for example, the title of a recent New York Times article:

> Independent Hotels **Are Disappearing** as Chains Grow [1](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/10/21/business/independent-hotels-airbnb-boutique-chains.html)

In this usage, I do not believe *disappear* is a stative verb. Oxford defines it as

> *disappear* (v) cease to be visible. [2](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/disappear)

With the example

> He **disappeared** into the trees.

This is not a state of being but rather an action.